# Removing 1 package wants to remove system packages Apt

Tags: apt, package-management, synaptic, delete

I'm trying to remove a specific package on Linux but removing this one package wants to remove a bunch of system critical packages. I don't want it to remove all these system packages when I only want to remove this one particular package which is causing issues trying to install other packages.

The package in question is the removal of `libdrm-amdgpu` but it wants to remove a bunch of packages that have no dependencies to it. I'm also in the process of trying to fix an issue with some applications requiring `libgcrypt11` package which doesn't exist in current Linux repos, besides older versions like Debian Wheezy, as most systems today have `libgcrypt20` which doesn't work for some applications particularly Source games from Steam like GMod, but I can't install it until this issue is fixed first.

While trying to perform `dist-upgrade` with APT I get this issue when upgrading, caused by a conflict issue of overwriting of an existing package;

```
Preparing to unpack .../libdrm-common_2.4.83+git20170905.d55d0804-0ubuntu0ricotz~16.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libdrm-common (2.4.83+git20170905.d55d0804-0ubuntu0ricotz~16.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libdrm-common_2.4.83+git20170905.d55d0804-0ubuntu0ricotz~16.04.1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/libdrm/amdgpu.ids', which is also in package libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 2.4.82+git20170725.3876bc24-0ubuntu0ricotz~16.04.1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libdrm-common_2.4.83+git20170905.d55d0804-0ubuntu0ricotz~16.04.1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

AMD GPU doesn't exist on this system, it's only Intel CPU/GPU and Nvidia GPU, and I want to remove that specific package, but it can't because of an overwrite issue, and it's hold on other dependencies that it doesn't need to be removing. I was just perhaps thinking I just delete the conflicting file `/usr/share/libdrm/amdgpu.ids` , but that may lead to other issues that I just can't be simply bothered with right now. Also simply force overwriting it will also break the system too so.

I'm using Linux Mint 18.2 FYI.

---

**EDIT:** Added Apt-Cache policy output.

```
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=LP-PPA-yannubuntu-boot-repair,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Boot-Repair,c=main,b=i386
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=LP-PPA-yannubuntu-boot-repair,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Boot-Repair,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/xorg-edgers/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=LP-PPA-xorg-edgers,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=xorg-edgers fresh X crack,c=main,b=i386
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/xorg-edgers/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=LP-PPA-xorg-edgers,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=xorg-edgers fresh X crack,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=LP-PPA-wine-wine-builds,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Official Wine builds,c=main,b=i386
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=LP-PPA-wine-wine-builds,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Official Wine builds,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/master-daily/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=LP-PPA-videolan-master-daily,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=VLC Daily Build of master branch,c=main,b=i386
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/master-daily/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=LP-PPA-videolan-master-daily,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=VLC Daily Build of master branch,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=LP-PPA-ubuntu-toolchain-r-test,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Toolchain test builds,c=main,b=i386
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=LP-PPA-ubuntu-toolchain-r-test,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Toolchain test builds,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://repo.steampowered.com/steam precise/steam i386 Packages
     release o=Valve Software LLC,n=precise,l=Steam,c=steam,b=i386
     origin repo.steampowered.com
 500 http://repo.steampowered.com/steam precise/steam amd64 Packages
     release o=Valve Software LLC,n=precise,l=Steam,c=steam,b=amd64
     origin repo.steampowered.com
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/random-stuff/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=LP-PPA-random-stuff,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Random Stuff "Daily/Nightly/Testing",c=main,b=i386
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/random-stuff/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=LP-PPA-random-stuff,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Random Stuff "Daily/Nightly/Testing",c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/paulo-miguel-dias/pkppa/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=LP-PPA-paulo-miguel-dias-pkppa,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Padoka Stable Mesa PPA,c=main,b=i386
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/paulo-miguel-dias/pkppa/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=LP-PPA-paulo-miguel-dias-pkppa,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Padoka Stable Mesa PPA,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openrct2/nightly/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=LP-PPA-openrct2-nightly,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=nightly ppa for OpenRCT2,c=main,b=i386
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openrct2/nightly/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=LP-PPA-openrct2-nightly,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=nightly ppa for OpenRCT2,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial/partner i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Canonical,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Partner archive,c=partner,b=i386
     origin archive.canonical.com
 500 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial/partner amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Canonical,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Partner archive,c=partner,b=amd64
     origin archive.canonical.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-security,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=i386
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-security,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=amd64
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-security,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=i386
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-security,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=amd64
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-security,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=i386
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-security,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=amd64
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-security,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=i386
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-security,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://ubuntu.mirror.digitalpacific.com.au/archive xenial-backports/universe i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-backports,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=i386
     origin ubuntu.mirror.digitalpacific.com.au
 500 http://ubuntu.mirror.digitalpacific.com.au/archive xenial-backports/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-backports,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=amd64
     origin ubuntu.mirror.digitalpacific.com.au
 500 http://ubuntu.mirror.digitalpacific.com.au/archive xenial-backports/main i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-backports,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=i386
     origin ubuntu.mirror.digitalpacific.com.au
 500 http://ubuntu.mirror.digitalpacific.com.au/archive xenial-backports/main amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-backports,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ubuntu.mirror.digitalpacific.com.au
 500 http://ubuntu.mirror.digitalpacific.com.au/archive xenial-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-updates,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=i386
     origin ubuntu.mirror.digitalpacific.com.au
 500 http://ubuntu.mirror.digitalpacific.com.au/archive xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-updates,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=amd64
     origin ubuntu.mirror.digitalpacific.com.au
 500 http://ubuntu.mirror.digitalpacific.com.au/archive xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-updates,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=i386
     origin ubuntu.mirror.digitalpacific.com.au
 500 http://ubuntu.mirror.digitalpacific.com.au/archive xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-updates,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=amd64
     origin ubuntu.mirror.digitalpacific.com.au
 500 http://ubuntu.mirror.digitalpacific.com.au/archive xenial-updates/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-updates,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=i386
     origin ubuntu.mirror.digitalpacific.com.au
 500 http://ubuntu.mirror.digitalpacific.com.au/archive xenial-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-updates,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=amd64
     origin ubuntu.mirror.digitalpacific.com.au
 500 http://ubuntu.mirror.digitalpacific.com.au/archive xenial-updates/main i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-updates,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=i386
     origin ubuntu.mirror.digitalpacific.com.au
 500 http://ubuntu.mirror.digitalpacific.com.au/archive xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-updates,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ubuntu.mirror.digitalpacific.com.au
 500 http://ubuntu.mirror.digitalpacific.com.au/archive xenial/multiverse i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=i386
     origin ubuntu.mirror.digitalpacific.com.au
 500 http://ubuntu.mirror.digitalpacific.com.au/archive xenial/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=amd64
     origin ubuntu.mirror.digitalpacific.com.au
 500 http://ubuntu.mirror.digitalpacific.com.au/archive xenial/universe i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=i386
     origin ubuntu.mirror.digitalpacific.com.au
 500 http://ubuntu.mirror.digitalpacific.com.au/archive xenial/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=amd64
     origin ubuntu.mirror.digitalpacific.com.au
 500 http://ubuntu.mirror.digitalpacific.com.au/archive xenial/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=i386
     origin ubuntu.mirror.digitalpacific.com.au
 500 http://ubuntu.mirror.digitalpacific.com.au/archive xenial/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=amd64
     origin ubuntu.mirror.digitalpacific.com.au
 500 http://ubuntu.mirror.digitalpacific.com.au/archive xenial/main i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=i386
     origin ubuntu.mirror.digitalpacific.com.au
 500 http://ubuntu.mirror.digitalpacific.com.au/archive xenial/main amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ubuntu.mirror.digitalpacific.com.au
 500 http://mirror.internode.on.net/pub/linuxmint-packages serena/backport i386 Packages
     release v=18.1,o=linuxmint,a=serena,n=serena,l=linuxmint,c=backport,b=i386
     origin mirror.internode.on.net
 500 http://mirror.internode.on.net/pub/linuxmint-packages serena/backport amd64 Packages
     release v=18.1,o=linuxmint,a=serena,n=serena,l=linuxmint,c=backport,b=amd64
     origin mirror.internode.on.net
 500 http://mirror.internode.on.net/pub/linuxmint-packages serena/import i386 Packages
     release v=18.1,o=linuxmint,a=serena,n=serena,l=linuxmint,c=import,b=i386
     origin mirror.internode.on.net
 500 http://mirror.internode.on.net/pub/linuxmint-packages serena/import amd64 Packages
     release v=18.1,o=linuxmint,a=serena,n=serena,l=linuxmint,c=import,b=amd64
     origin mirror.internode.on.net
 700 http://mirror.internode.on.net/pub/linuxmint-packages serena/upstream i386 Packages
     release v=18.1,o=linuxmint,a=serena,n=serena,l=linuxmint,c=upstream,b=i386
     origin mirror.internode.on.net
 700 http://mirror.internode.on.net/pub/linuxmint-packages serena/upstream amd64 Packages
     release v=18.1,o=linuxmint,a=serena,n=serena,l=linuxmint,c=upstream,b=amd64
     origin mirror.internode.on.net
 500 http://mirror.internode.on.net/pub/linuxmint-packages serena/main i386 Packages
     release v=18.1,o=linuxmint,a=serena,n=serena,l=linuxmint,c=main,b=i386
     origin mirror.internode.on.net
 500 http://mirror.internode.on.net/pub/linuxmint-packages serena/main amd64 Packages
     release v=18.1,o=linuxmint,a=serena,n=serena,l=linuxmint,c=main,b=amd64
     origin mirror.internode.on.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=LP-PPA-obsproject-obs-studio,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=OBS Studio,c=main,b=i386
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=LP-PPA-obsproject-obs-studio,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=OBS Studio,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/moka/daily/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=LP-PPA-moka-daily,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Moka Daily,c=main,b=i386
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/moka/daily/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=LP-PPA-moka-daily,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Moka Daily,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 https://mega.nz/linux/MEGAsync/xUbuntu_15.10 ./ Packages
     release o=obs://private/DEB/xUbuntu_15.10,n=xUbuntu_15.10,l=DEB,c=
     origin mega.nz
 500 http://prerelease.keybase.io/deb stable/main i386 Packages
     release n=stable,c=main,b=i386
     origin prerelease.keybase.io
 500 http://prerelease.keybase.io/deb stable/main amd64 Packages
     release n=stable,c=main,b=amd64
     origin prerelease.keybase.io
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kdenlive/kdenlive-stable/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=LP-PPA-kdenlive-kdenlive-stable,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Kdenlive release,c=main,b=i386
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kdenlive/kdenlive-stable/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=LP-PPA-kdenlive-kdenlive-stable,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Kdenlive release,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://apt.izzysoft.de/ubuntu generic/universe all Packages
     release a=generic,c=universe,b=all
     origin apt.izzysoft.de
 500 http://apt.izzysoft.de/ubuntu generic/universe i386 Packages
     release a=generic,c=universe,b=i386
     origin apt.izzysoft.de
 500 http://apt.izzysoft.de/ubuntu generic/universe amd64 Packages
     release a=generic,c=universe,b=amd64
     origin apt.izzysoft.de
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=LP-PPA-graphics-drivers,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Proprietary GPU Drivers,c=main,b=i386
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=LP-PPA-graphics-drivers,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Proprietary GPU Drivers,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main amd64 Packages
     release v=1.0,o=Google, Inc.,a=stable,n=stable,l=Google,c=main,b=amd64
     origin dl.google.com
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/dolphin-emu/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=LP-PPA-dolphin-emu,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Dolphin Emulator PPA,c=main,b=i386
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/dolphin-emu/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=LP-PPA-dolphin-emu,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Dolphin Emulator PPA,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=LP-PPA-danielrichter2007-grub-customizer,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Launchpad PPA for Grub Customizer,c=main,b=i386
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=LP-PPA-danielrichter2007-grub-customizer,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Launchpad PPA for Grub Customizer,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  Packages
     release o=NVIDIA,l=NVIDIA CUDA,c=
     origin developer.download.nvidia.com
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ci-train-ppa-service/stable-phone-overlay/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=LP-PPA-ci-train-ppa-service-stable-phone-overlay,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Stable Phone Overlay PPA,c=main,b=i386
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ci-train-ppa-service/stable-phone-overlay/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=LP-PPA-ci-train-ppa-service-stable-phone-overlay,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Stable Phone Overlay PPA,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/berfenger/roccat/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=LP-PPA-berfenger-roccat,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Roccat Tools,c=main,b=i386
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/berfenger/roccat/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=LP-PPA-berfenger-roccat,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Roccat Tools,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://storage.googleapis.com/bazel-apt stable/jdk1.8 amd64 Packages
     release o=Bazel Authors,n=stable,l=Bazel,c=jdk1.8,b=amd64
     origin storage.googleapis.com
 500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=dl.winehq.org,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=winehq,c=main,b=i386
     origin dl.winehq.org
 500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=dl.winehq.org,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=winehq,c=main,b=amd64
     origin dl.winehq.org
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/snwh/pulp/ubuntu yakkety/main i386 Packages
     release v=16.10,o=LP-PPA-snwh-pulp,a=yakkety,n=yakkety,l=Paper Themes (Daily Builds),c=main,b=i386
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/snwh/pulp/ubuntu yakkety/main amd64 Packages
     release v=16.10,o=LP-PPA-snwh-pulp,a=yakkety,n=yakkety,l=Paper Themes (Daily Builds),c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo debian-stretch/main amd64 Packages
     release o=Docker,a=debian-stretch,n=debian-stretch,l=Docker APT Repository,c=main,b=amd64
     origin apt.dockerproject.org
Pinned packages:
```

Comment: You're probably mixing packages from sources that shouldn't be mixed. Please paste the output of `apt-cache policy` into your question.

Comment: @FaheemMitha - Most times I have no choice because certain packages do not exist in the current repos that have to be manually added to have them.

Comment: You might be better off using something like Debian, then. And what examples of packages are you missing? In any case, adding entire "foreign" repositories will not lead to anything good happening. You can add packages individually without adding an entire repository. In any case, `apt-cache policy`, please.

Comment: Yikes, that's tons of stuff. For future reference, adding tons of repositories is not a great idea, and will, with high probability, lead to problems.

Comment: `apt-cache policy libdrm-common libdrm-amdgpu1` please. Most likely, at least one of these shouldn't be installed.

Comment: @FaheemMitha - I can't get half these packages in the main repos, and no I don't want to be just using pure Debian. Some others are installed from stand alone Deb packages, and not from a manually added repo. I've always carefully selected the packages I needed as required for the things that I use. That plus building packages from source file, the default repo doesn't always have what I need to compile things. The package I don't want is the `libdrm-amdgpu1` which is what's causing issues here.